# How to append a DataFrame to a multiindex DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Suppose that I have the DataFrames

```
In [1]: a=pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]],  
   ...:     index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([('A','B'),('d','e')]))                                    

In [2]: a                                                                                               
Out[2]: 
     0  1
A d  1  2
  e  3  4
B d  5  6
  e  7  8

In [3]: b=pd.DataFrame([[9,10],[11,12]],index=('d','e'))                                                

In [4]: b                                                                                               
Out[4]: 
    0   1
d   9  10
e  11  12
```

and I want to append `b` to `a`, with the subindex `C`, producing the 
`DataFrame`

```
      0   1
A d   1   2
  e   3   4
B d   5   6
  e   7   8
C d   9  10
  e  11  12
```

I tried

```
In [5]: a.loc['C'] = b
```

but got

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign a new value to `b` , then `set_index` and `swaplevel` before `append` to `a`

```
a.append(b.assign(k='C').set_index('k',append=True).swaplevel(0,1))
Out[33]: 
      0   1
A d   1   2
  e   3   4
B d   5   6
  e   7   8
C d   9  10
  e  11  12
```

Comment: I used this same technique except instead of append, I used pd.conat.

Comment: Thanks, it was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

First update b's index to match the same levels as a, then concat:

```
b.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([('C','C'), ('d','e')])
pd.concat([a,b]))])
```

Comment: Thank you Kyle, this is a good solution, but I like best the one from @Wen-Ben, because it does not change the original dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

If wanna step-by-step;

```
df2 = pd.concat([a,b], ignore_index=True)
df2['i0'] = a.index.get_level_values(0).tolist() + ['C']*len(b)
df2['i1'] = a.index.get_level_values(0).union(b.index)
df2.set_index(['i0', 'i1'])
```

Outputs

```
         0  1
i0  i1      
A   A   1   2
A       3   4
B   B   5   6
B       7   8
C   d   9   10
e       11  12
```