# Pandas : Append a dataframe to particular index in a multi-index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index, pandas-loc

Say I have a dataframe :

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["A", "B"], ["AA", "BB"]])
columns = ["X", "Y"]
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[5,8],[1,2],[5,8]], index = index, columns = columns)

      X  Y
A AA  1  2
  BB  5  8
B AA  1  2
  BB  5  8
```

I want to append insert a dataframe with index value `C` to the same dataframe

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,4], [5,6]], index =  ["AAA", "BBB"], columns = columns)

     X  Y
AAA  1  4
BBB  5  6
```

So that my dataframe looks like

**Expected Output :**

```
        X    Y
A   AA  1    2
    BB  5    8
B   AA  1    2
    BB  5    8
C  AAA  1    4
   BBB  5    6
```

**What I tried :**

```
df.loc['C',:] = df2
```

which does NOT give me expected output

```
        X    Y
A AA  1.0  2.0
  BB  5.0  8.0
B AA  1.0  2.0
  BB  5.0  8.0
C     NaN  NaN
```

Comment: As per the answer to the suggested [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54469814/how-to-append-a-dataframe-to-a-multiindex-dataframe), you could use: `df.append(df2.assign(k='C').set_index('k', append=True).swaplevel(0,1))`. Or now rather: `pd.concat([df,df2.assign(k='C').set_index('k', append=True).swaplevel(0,1)])` with `df.append` being deprecated.

Comment: @ouroboros1 liked ZLi answer better!

Comment: Yes, it is better. With `pd.concat` it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add a new index level to `df2` first:

```
df.append(pd.concat({'C': df2}))
```

As @ouroboros mentioned `df.append` is being [deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html#whatsnew-140-deprecations-frame-series-append), the suggested syntax is now `pd.concat([df, pd.concat({'C': df2})])`

Comment: or `pd.concat([df, pd.concat({'C': df2})])`, since `.append` is deprecated